# React - Test if conditionally rendered elements in component are rendered when state changes with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a ReactElement in my component which is rendered if a state attribute is set. Now I would like to test that behaviour by setting the state inside of my test and check if the element has been rendered afterwards. If I update the state by using `setState({key: object})` on the mounted wrapper, its seems like it has no effect on my component although the state of the wrapper has been updated. Am I  doing the state update at the wrong place?

#### MyComponent.tsx

```
class MyCompoonent extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        ....
        // Render <div> if state is set
        {this.state.myObject && (<div>Test me</div>)}
    }
}
```

#### MyTest.tsx

```
...
it('should render div if state is set', () => {
    
    // Create fake object
    const fakeObject: FakeObjectType = { name: "fake" }; 
    
    // Mount component
    const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
   
    // Update state
    wrapper.setState({
        myObject: fakeObject
    }, () => {
        
        // Prints fakeObject as part of state
        console.log(wrapper.state());

        // I don´t think I need that?!
        wrapper.update();
        
        // Wrapper has not been rerendered,
        // <div> is still not part of the printed output
        console.log(wrapper.debug());

        // Test failes ;(
        expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<div>Test me</div>)).toBeTruthy();
    }
});
```

Comment: it looks like when you set the state in the test you need to add `myObject` inside `form` since you use `this.state.form.myObject` in the component

Comment: My bad @WebbH. The `this.state.form.myObject` is a leftover from my actual use case where I have a nested attribute inside of state. I have removed it now from the simplified example above.